# Mod Rewrite append .php to string in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK so I've found every rendition of this but not this specifically. So my urls are in this format

```
www.inspection.com/users/?action=register
```

I want to convert it to

```
www.inspection.com/users.php?action=register
```

Here's what I've got so far in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9]+/\?action=[A-Za-z0-9]+$ $1.php?action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But error logs say  **RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression**

Main Goal: After the domain name is the reference to the file I want to call. So append php on the end of that string but keep the query parameters

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also make sure that your .htaccess rules file and .php file are residing on same folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)/?\?action=(.+)$ $1.php?action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

One more thing, you have not created a capturing group on left side of RewriteRule hence you can't use them on the right side of it.

Comment: @swg1cor14, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Please explain your regex to make it easier to understand.